# How to Add Multiple QPushButton to QGraphicsScene and Set Scene to QGraphics View in QT?

Tags: qt

How to Add Multiple QPushButton to QGraphicsScene and Set Scene to QGraphics View in QT ?

I want to Add 5 buttons to Graphics Scene but it adds only one button.

```
int i =  5 ;
    btnuser = new QPushButton();   
    btnuser->setGeometry(QRect(0,0,480,47));   
    scene = new QGraphicsScene(0,0,480,272);
    btnuser->setText("Test User");     
    for(i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++ )
    {
         QGraphicsProxyWidget *proxy = scene->addWidget(btnuser);

    }
    ui->graphicsView->setScene(scene);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to create 5 buttons then:

```
int i =  5 ;
scene = new QGraphicsScene(0,0,480,272);
for(i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++ )
{
   btnuser = new QPushButton();
   btnuser->setGeometry(QRect(<where_you_want_not_the_same!>));
   btnuser->setText("Test User");
   QGraphicsProxyWidget *proxy = scene->addWidget(btnuser);
}
ui->graphicsView->setScene(scene);
```

The proxy pattern acts just as an "interface".